# How to block all trafic outside home network and VPN by patching Android code?

Tags: root-access, networking, lineageos, vpn

I would like to patch LineageOS on my phone so it

- opens Wireguard tunnel through the 4G network to the home network
- routes all traffic from Android applications through a Wireguard tunnel or through the home network

I am really not sure which layer of Android should I patch. I was thinking about changing `ip rule` and `ip route`, but I am not sure if it is the best possible.

Can you imagine anything more faster than this?
Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with the **Always-On VPN** function?

Comment: @Robert I don't know how to automatically deactivate it, when I come to my home network. VPN server is in other building and I don't want ping pong traffic across my network.